# allow scroll of div set behind another div

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have a iPad frame and want to have a larger image behind it (the page content) that scrolls down as you scroll. My css is more complicated then the example in the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/vk0jk37v/ but I cant seem to get even this to work.

in my real webpage I want to scroll down normally until I get to this image, then I want the scroll to effect the "page content" in this image. After I want to allow the user to continue scrolling normally after the "page content" of the image ends.

Edit: I have updated the fiddle and it rough but essentially what I am looking for except when I set the iPad frame to be on top of the image I am unable to get the content to scroll. the reason I need it under is to keep the image together when resizing the window with out covering the "fixed nav" or black side lines. Any thoughts on this? and thank you Felk for the hint in the right direction

Edit2: the image attached is the context in which I am applying this.

example html

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="frame" src="http://s11.postimg.org/44ejhu0jn/ipad_frame_780.png" />
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/xtwbnx937/ipad_content_660.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

example css

```
.container {
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;
}
.frame {
    /* position: absolute; */
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
 .inner {
    height: 558px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 14%;
    left: 38px;
}
.inner img {
    width: 92%;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood your question propely. I think i do now. If time I'll try to work on an answer tomorrow but it will be more complicated that the wrong answer already gave to you. Btw the need of javascript will be needed.anyway the basics to get what you want will be similar

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, sorry for the bad explanation. It was still very helpful

Comment: Currently you can achieve this with sticky positioning of elements in Firefox and Opera. Chrome is working on re-implementing it and Microsoft is considering adding it to the upcoming Microsoft Edge. Search for `position: sticky;` for more info. Until it gets broader support, though, you'll need to use JavaScript to achieve this. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/gv9ugaw9/1/) in Firefox to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was trying to fix your fiddle but at the end I have changed too much.

I will explain thought what I would do if I wanted to do your project. (hopefully if I have understood your question well enough).

First at all I would position the image of the ipad at the background with  `position:fixed` and negative `z-index`. Now we have the image NOT moving at all as the position is placed relative to the window and not to any element. And also we have the first part of your content over the image and scrolling nicely.

Then we focus on the right flow of the html elements when scrolling so basically there will be more content under the first (and later under the image). I have added another div with red background to illustrate better the problem.

The html would look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer">
        <img class="" src="http://s11.postimg.org/xtwbnx937/ipad_content_660.png"/>
    </div>
        <div class="frame">
    <img class="ipad" src="http://s11.postimg.org/44ejhu0jn/ipad_frame_780.png" />
        </div>

    <div class="moreContent"></div>

</div>
```

Now we focus just on separate the top content from the bottom content. To do this we just add a big `margin-bottom` to the first content. Now when scrolling once you reach the end of the first content the image at the background will show then after the margin is over the last content will start flowing over the image (which is what you don't want)

basically we have this: **[FIDDLE1](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/vk0jk37v/11/)**

Now it's just time to do a very simple jquery (it's always simple if I can use it). We just need to give some orders to the browser so I have used this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1127) {
                $(".frame").addClass('relative');
                $(".outer").addClass('no-margin');
            } 
             else {
                $(".frame").removeClass('relative');
                $(".outer").removeClass('no-margin');
            }           
        });
```

basically I'm telling the browser that when the scroll is higher than 1227px (height) to add a class to `frame` and another to `outer` and if you scroll back to remove the classes.

Then The class I add to `outer`  will just remove the big margin between first and last divs while the class add to `frame` will just make the container of the image relative so the flow of the html is normal and the image will keep scrolling down with the rest of elements.

Of course the 1227px I choose is based on the jsfiddle images you provided but in your future projects it won't be too hard to find the real height of your first content justinpecting it with chrome or simillar. same with the big margin I added.

The rest of changes was to make the sizes correct and center all elements in the window with at 600px width.

Here you have the final **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/vk0jk37v/12/)**

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I really appreciate the well written answer you gave me. I am just having trouble getting it to work. I added a image to highlight what I am trying to do. I think your solution may work but I need to find a way to get it to work while not using position fixed (or perhaps using it only while the element is scrolling), as well as to have the image scroll within the ipad. Thanks again and I will mark your answer as right if I am able to get it to work. In the mean time I still need help.

Comment: back home but today's late. I have been thinking about what you want to achieve and honestly, even if am going to think about it tomorrow morning (I can't help myself), today, as tired as I am, I can't find any "easy" way to do what you want. It can be done for sure, but if your project, idea and design was mine... I am sure I would have to spend many hours just getting the effect right (proably more than a day's work) and while I like to spend some time helping here (as so often, like daily, any doubt I have is solved in stackoverflow) i don't think I will work so many hours to help you.

Comment: Sorry about it. still I will think about an easy way to do this and maybe tomorrow, fresh and awake, I may find I'm missing something. WIll let you know if so

Comment: No worries Alvaro, thank you so much for your help and responses!

Comment: Hey Alvaro, you spent quite a bit of time helping me with this so i thought you might be interested in the solution i ended up with with the help of benny and yourself jsfiddle.net/pkt6xnb5/5 Thanks again!

Comment: that's a very nice solution using transform to "scroll" the content. Grats on it, well thought