# scroll page then at certian position scroll element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am at a bit of a loss for how how to do this.

I have a web page. I want a user to scroll down, then at a specific distance from the top I want the mouse scroll to effect an elements position (making it appear as thought that element is scrolling). then when that element hits a position (ie top: -500) I want the scroll to apply to the main webpage again. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Im working on a fiddle now but not having any luck, I will post when I have something to show

Edit: The beginning of a solution/sudo code https://jsfiddle.net/vk0jk37v/23/

Attached is an image of one area in which I am applying this.

```
//pageFeature.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + parseInt(-y / 6) + 'px'); 

var element = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect();
var elementTop = element.top //distance from top 720;

// variable to stop function from being replayed on scroll when scrolling image
var isScrollingImage = false;

// disables scroll on body
var disableScroll = function() {
    document.body.style.overflow='hidden';
}
// enables scroll on body
var enableScroll = function() {
    document.body.style.overflow='auto';
}
//change position of background along y axis with scroll
var scrollImage = function() {
    console.log("called");
   isScrollingImage = true;
   var pageFeature = document.getElementById("inner");
   var pageFeaturePosition;
   pageFeature.style.backgroundPositionY=parseInt(-scrollY / 10) + "px";
    //if (background is scrolled to bottom) {
    //    enableScroll();
    // }
}

//when element gets to center of viewport and animation is scroll is not on element
//call scrollImage()
function checkPosition() {
    if (scrollY > 720 && !isScrollingImage) {
        disableScroll();
        scrollImage();
    }
    //isScrollingImage = false;
}

//once out of view port will have to bring the image back down, 
//scroll image will only happen on the way down

document.addEventListener('scroll', checkPosition);
```

[image]

Comment: you can use onscroll event and check once that elements position at required place. You can scroll page back to its position

Comment: Didn't you ask the same like 45 minutes ago? . At least check answers there in case someone has post an answer. And changing the title does not make a question less duplicated

Comment: hi  Alvaro, I am looking at your answer to my last question right now and will post there in a minute. In the other question I am looking for a css solution and with this one I am looking for a js solution. I am concerned with my layout I may have to look at a using js to do this (I am applying this in more then one context). Thank you for a great response in the other question. for anyone interested he is referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852865/allow-scroll-of-div-set-behind-another-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var thresholdY = 150; 
    var thresholdCounter = 0; 
    var speed = 4; 
    var element = document.getElementById('yourElement'); 

    window.onscroll = function(event) { 
      if(scrollY > thresholdY) { 
        window.scrollTo(0, thresholdY); 
        element.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate3d(0,' + (--thresholdCounter * speed) + 'px,0);'); 
        return false; 
      }
      return null; 
    };
```

**Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pkt6xnb5/**

The idea here is that you keep the window in place when the user reaches a certain threshold Y position. Also at that time we transform the element along it's Y axis in the opposite direction the user is scrolling to make it move up as they scroll further down. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: hi benny I think this will work, Im just working on getting it to work in my fiddle (i need the scroll to be controlled by the mouse/tabs not just an animation but I think the logic will work). I will mark the answer as right when I have it working. Thanks!

Comment: @ReganPerkins Ah okay, there are probably a couple ways to do it. I haven't tested it, but this seems like it should work (edited the answer)

Comment: @ReganPerkins Okay I had time to get to a computer and I now realize it's a little more complicated. This fiddle should work for what you're asking for, but you'll have to write additional logic for it to work in reverse as well (if that's what you want): https://jsfiddle.net/pkt6xnb5/

Comment: Thank you so much benny! I though I was going to be stck on this forever. For anyone else interested the final fiddle to do what i wanted is https://jsfiddle.net/pkt6xnb5/5/ I will update it with the final touches when I can but the behaviour is all there.

Comment: @ReganPerkins Sweet, your fiddle works for me too. I think `event.preventDefault()` is a rogue line from the previous code and can be removed.